# Typescript errors on what should be a basic object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following error in my typescript, and I have no idea how to get around it?

> Parameter 'key' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Below is my code, I don't fully understand the problem, even if I type them `any` I get the error?

```
  let store = {};

  return {
    getItem: (key) => {
      return store[key] || null;
    },
    setItem: (key, value) => {
      store[key] = value.toString();
    },
    removeItem: (key) => {
      delete store[key];
    },
    clear: () => {
      store = {};
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: If you check your `tsconfig` file, you most likely have `noImplicitAny` enabled, which would cause this error.

Comment: Don't disable `--noImplicitAny`, it's there for a good reason.  Do you want someone to call `setItem(new Date(), null)`?  If not, you need to annotate your types.  What type of data do you want `store` to hold?  Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8A5dN) work for your use cases? If so I can maybe write up an answer; if not, please [edit] the example to demonstrate any unmet needs.

Comment: I've sorted it now solution added above.

Comment: @Udders you can enter your solution in the Answers area and mark it as solved, as well, so it won't show up under unsolved questions, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was typing the key at the point of the object creation

```
const fakeLocalStorage = () => {
      let store: { [key: string]: string } = {};
    
      return {
        getItem: (key: string) => {
          return store[key] || null;
        },
        setItem: (key: string, value: string) => {
          store[key] = value.toString();
        },
        removeItem: (key: string) => {
          delete store[key];
        },
        clear: () => {
          store = {};
        },
      };
    };
```